# Applying System.Linq.Expression to a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I already have a predefined expression and I also have a List.
How can I then apply and invoke the expression on that list?
For e.g.
Linq Expression looks something like this:

```
{Foo[]..Where(o => (o.AuditDateTime > 20/04/2018 00:00:00)).Take(10)}}
```

I have seperate List of Foo already.

So I want to basically apply the expression on the list of Foo with end result being of top 10 items from the list with the predicate of `(o.AuditDateTime > 20/04/2018 00:00:00)` applied.

Comment: What's the exact signature of your Expression?  `Expression<Func<Foo[], IEnumerable<Foo>>>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
// expression can be centralized somewhere
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> fooFilter = (_) => _.AuditDateTime > new DateTime(2018,4,20);

// from somewhere
Foo[] existingFooList;

var resulting10Foos = existingFooList.Where(fooFilter).Take(10);
```

Comment: Is it possible I can grab the IQueryable Expression from one object and apply it another one without having to rebuild it? The above option of centralising is not really an option and I also want to use other Take() of the original expression?

Answer (score 0):

**Where** in Linq accepts delegate which has a signature of Func

```
Func<Foo, bool> myDelegate = delegate(Foo foo)
{
    return foo.AuditDateTime > new DateTime(2018,4,20);
};
```

Then use it in where

```
existingFooList.Where(myDelegate).Take(10);
```

Comment: Same issue as @Igor above but not really what I need. I can create a predicate already.